# Probability Question: Box and Balls: Please solve

Tags: probability

A box contains 100 balls, of which r are red. Suppose that the balls are drawn from the box one at a time, at random, without replacement. Determine (a) the probability that the first ball drawn will be red; (b)the probability that the 50th ball drawn will be red; and(c)the probability that the last ball drawn will be red.

Please solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: I think all questions have the same answer.

Comment: @Tunococ is correct, i think. and it's the ovious answer too - $\frac{r}{100}$

Comment: Will anyone of you please explain why all have the same answers?

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 7 questions during 2 or 3 last days. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $$\binom{100}{r}$$ sequences of length $100$ consisting of $r$ red balls and $100-r$ non-red balls.

The number of sequences in which the first ball is red is $\binom{99}{r-1}$.  The number of sequences in which the 50-th ball is red is $\binom{99}{r-1}$.  The number of sequences in which the 100-th ball is red is $\binom{99}{r-1}$.

In fact, for any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,100\}$, the number of sequences in which the $i$-th ball is red is $\binom{99}{r-1}$.

Hence, for any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,100\}$, the probability that the $i$-th ball is red is $$\frac{\binom{99}{r-1}}{\binom{100}{r}}=\frac{r}{100}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$A_i$ ={Draw Red at step i}
think of arranging the ball in 100 spots in a row.
P($A_1$) = r/100.
P($A_{50}$) =?
sample space = sequence of length 50.
N(S) = 100*99*....*50 = $p_{(100,50)}$.
N($A_{50}$) = r$*$$p_{(99,49)}$ red on 50. there are 99 balls left.
r choices to put red on 50.
P($A_{50}$) = r/100.
etc